# How to push data from server to client without using open sockets?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, chat, apple-push-notifications, instant-messaging

I am developing a chat app, something that many before me have done so I would expect to get a clear answer to my question but I can not find one anywhere.

So the question is: **How to push data from server to client without using open sockets?**
(When I say data i mean admin messages of the system)

I can think of two approaches:

1. Polling - client will "ask" the server every few seconds if there is new data waiting for him.
   The problem with this approach is that it kills the battery very fast.
2. APNS (Apple push notification service) - whenever server has new data he will send a push notification to the client that there is new data waiting for him (the push does't carry the data itself), this will trigger a "getData" request from client to server.

This approach means that I need to send "silent" push (without showing alert to the user), and I'm not sure this is a good use of the APNS.

Any thoughts about this? maybe other better approaches?